# Error when running rails g rspec:install in AWS cloud9 terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, cloud9-ide, aws-cloud9

I'm creating a rails app using AWS Cloud9 (`Rails v.5.0.0, Ruby v.2.6.3`) and have successfully installed rspec with `gem install rspec` and added `gem 'rspec-rails'` to my `:development, :test` block in the gemfile and did a  `bundle install`

**Problem**
When I try to run the command `rails g rspec:install` in the terminal, I get the following:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 7356
Could not find generator 'rspec:install'. Maybe you meant 'assets', 'channel' or 'scaffold'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

**Expected** I am expecting:

```
no examples found
finished in x seconds...
0 examples, 0 failures
```

**What I have tried**

1. Adding `gem 'rspec-rails'` outside the `:development, :test` block in the gemfile, then `bundle install`
2. Specifying the version (5.0)
3. disabling the spring preloader
4. tried the following commands:

```
bin/rails g rspec:install 
bundle exec rails g rspec:install 
bundle exec bin/rails g rspec:install
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the rails environment of your app in AWS Cloud9  you can check by running `rails r "puts Rails.env"`

Comment: I ran that command and this was the output: ```Running via Spring preloader in process 11867
development```

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the gem with `bundle install` after adding it to the Gemfile. So just run `bundle install` then re-run `rails g rspec:install`

*you can check if the gem is installed in your project by running `bundle info rspec-rails`*

if this is not working you probably need to set the environment to `development` by setting `RAILS_ENV=development` or (`test`), however

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention I have done bundle install. still the same error.

Comment: @KatieEdmonds have you tried running `bin/rails g rspec:install` or `bundle exec rails g rspec:install` or even `bundle exec bin/rails g rspec:install`?

Comment: @KatieEdmonds also please can you try runnin `bundle info rspec-rails` and let me know what it outputs?

Comment: I ran everything in your first comment and same error. I then ran ```bundle info rspec-rails``` and got the following output: ```The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Could not find gem 'rspec-rails'.```

Comment: you may be missing the RAILS_ENV set in your environment, I updated the answer, good luck

Comment: thank you! I will give it a try :) it's my first time using the cloud for an app too